# Collision game using JQuery UI Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created one of those unblock games where you have to move obstacles from your way in order to drag main block to the target. In my example, red rectangle into the yellow one and that works as expected, but what I'm missing is collision effect (right now blocks go through each other).

I have tried several methods, such as **obstacle: ".obstacle"** as defined in [JQuery UI Draggable documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/jquidragcollide/wiki/Home/), but I can't get it to work. In original documentation they gave few examples, but those obstacles are't movable. Can somebody help me with this?

Here is [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48pxtzmr/3/) working example (with UI Draggable Collision).

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-block-area">
    <div id="hero-block" class="collider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="enemy-block-area">
    <div id="enemy-block" class="obstacle"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="Target1" class="target"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hero-block").draggable({ containment: ".hero-block-area", obstacle: ".obstacle" });
  $("#enemy-block").draggable({ containment: ".enemy-block-area" });
  $("#Target1").droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    preventCollision: true,
    drop: dropItem
  });
});

function dropItem(ev, ui) {
  alert("NICE!");
}
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  overlay: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  display: block;
}

.target {
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  right: 0px;
  background: yellow;
}

.hero-block-area {
  top: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#hero-block {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.enemy-block-area {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
}

#enemy-block {
  background: brown;
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure 'obstacle' is a built in option of jquery UI's draggable? I think it might be a seperate plugin which you need to import: https://github.com/dsbaars/jq-ui-draggable-collision

Comment: Yes it is separate plugin but I did import it, for that option alone.

Comment: Ok because it doesn't look like it is imported in the jsfiddle example.